# How to resolve NoSuchMethodError from custom library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two projects, call them A and B.   A uses instances of B in its functionality.  I needed to add a method to B.  So I added the method and increased the minor version number of library B.  I've updated the pom.xml of A to use the new version of B.

When I build project A with maven, it runs fine - but when trying to run in Eclipse, I get a NoSuchMethodError when it attempts to call the new method.  Eclipse does, however, recognize the new method in autocomplete when I call it from A.

I've confirmed project B is in the build path for project A.  I've tried cleaning both projects.  I've tried changing the name of the method and rebuilding.  No luck.

In case it matters, there are two other projects used by A that also use B.  They use the older version of B (3.0 vs 3.1).  The dependency hierarchy tab for pom.xml says it's ignoring the older version, though.

I apologize if this is an obvious question, but I'm trying to maintain this code without having much of a Java background.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to run the generated  jar file outside of Eclipse? The "build path" is not an indicator of the application's "classpath".

Comment: Perhaps your run configuration is using a customized classpath - have you checked the run configuration to see which version of B it is using?

Comment: The run configuration classpath doesn't show B at all, @D.B.  It just shows the JRE, "Maven Dependencies", and project A.

Comment: Does it show maven dependencies?

Comment: Where is the Eclipse jar stored that I should try to run @cricket_007?

Comment: Yes, @D.B. It does.

Comment: Maven makes a `target/` folder with the generated JAR file when you build it typically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - this was a comment, but since it did solve the problem I have deleted the comment in favor of an answer as I think it will be easier to read this way.

Based on everything you've said so far it seems like the classpath is set up correctly, but my thoughts keep coming back to something with the runtime classpath is incorrect. You said, "there are two other projects used by A that also use B. They use the older version of B (3.0 vs 3.1)" and even though the dependency hierarchy says it's pulling the 3.1 version maybe Eclipse is not abiding by that and it's pulling 3.0 for some reason. So my suggestion would be to update the other two projects and see what happens.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!